# What will happen if I remove Shotwell?

Tags: 11.10, shotwell

If I install gThumb and make it my preferred image viewer, then what will happen if I remove Shotwell?

I'm asking because, in Unity's dash, there is a huge Shotwell icon that says "view photos". So, I'm wondering what will happen to that icon and Ubuntu's default photo viewer.

Comment: Shotwell will get uninstalled..

Comment: Well, yes. But will Ubuntu replace the "view photos" massive icon with?

Comment: this icon should disappear as a normal routine of the uninstallation process. You might want to add a shortcut to gThumb then.

Comment: If the Dash icon is integrated into the Dash itself and it's not dependent on Shotwell, it will not ge away if you remove Shotwell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shotwell will get uninstalled and icon will disappear and the default viewer will revert back to Image Viewer if u had made Shotwell your default image viewer

PS: your config files will still be present , so instead or apt-get remove use apt-get purge command to completely remove Shotwell

Comment: One more thing I had to do was manually remove the files `/usr/share/applications/shotwell.desktop` and `/usr/share/applications/shotwell-viewer.desktop`. These files were not removed with the package (even with purge), and caused `/etc/mailcap` to associate image files with shotwell.

Answer (score 0):

After removal set Gthumb or something else to your default image viewer under system settings/ system info/ default applications. Then it will replace the shotwell icon in unity "view photos".

Answer (score 0):

You can easilly test it out. Just do a

```
sudo apt-get remove shotwell
```

If something goes wrong, you still can reinstall it, config should stay. You can btw just delete the icon if it stays and add a new one for gTumb.